# Create HTTP GET in C return 301 redirect using IP address

Tags: c, sockets, httprequest, httpresponse, http-redirect

I want to send a GET request to a page and retrieve it to use later to a crawler
I have implemented my own D.N.S. resolver (like DIG command in LINUX) and I want to use the ip address to get the http page
I have the following code

```
        typedef struct http_request
        {
            request_type req_type;
            char* ip;
            int port_number;
            char* path;
            char* data;
            char* hostname;
        }http_request;

        typedef struct http_response
        {
            char* raw_response;
            int status_code;
            char* status_text;
            char* body;
            char* server_name;
            int content_length;
            char* content_type;
        }http_response;
    // main method
    http_response* send_http_request(http_request* request) {
        if (request == NULL) {
            printf("HTTP request is NULL.\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        http_response* response = (http_response*) malloc(sizeof(http_response));
        if (response == NULL) {
            exit(1);
            return NULL;
        }

        char http_request_buffer[REQUEST_BUFF_SIZE];
        memset(http_request_buffer, 0, REQUEST_BUFF_SIZE);
        sprintf(http_request_buffer, "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:%s\r\n\r\n",
                request->path, request->ip);
        process_http_request(request, http_request_buffer, response);
        return response;
    }
static int process_http_request(http_request* request,
        char* http_request_buffer, http_response* response) {
    int socketfd;
    struct sockaddr_in socket_details;
    char temp_buffer[TEMP_BUFF_SIZE];
    char* http_response_buffer;
    ssize_t bytes_sent = 0;
    ssize_t total_bytes_sent = 0;
    ssize_t bytes_received = 0;
    ssize_t total_bytes_received = 0;
    int status;

    http_response_buffer = (char*) malloc(RESPONSE_BUFF_SIZE);
    if (http_response_buffer == NULL) {
        printf(
                "process_http_request: memory allocation failed for response buffer.\n");
        return HTTP_ERROR_MEM_ALLOC_FAILED;
    }
    memset(http_response_buffer, 0, RESPONSE_BUFF_SIZE);

    socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (socketfd == -1) {
        printf("process_http_request: socket creation failed.\n");
        return HTTP_ERROR_SOCKET_CREATION_FAILED;
    }

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec = 5;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    if (setsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *) &timeout,
            sizeof(timeout)) < 0)
        printf("process_http_request: socket option setting failed.\n");

    bzero(&socket_details, sizeof(socket_details));
    socket_details.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socket_details.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(request->ip);
    socket_details.sin_port = htons(request->port_number);

    if (connect(socketfd, (struct sockaddr*) &socket_details,
            sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) {
        printf("process_http_request: Could not connect to the server.\n");
        return HTTP_ERROR_SERVER_CONN_FAILED;
    }

    while (1) {
        bytes_sent = send(socketfd, http_request_buffer,
                strlen(http_request_buffer), 0);
        if (bytes_sent < 0) {
            printf("process_http_request: error writing on socket\n");
            close(socketfd);
            return HTTP_ERROR_SOCKET_WRITE_FAILED;
        } else {
            printf(
                    "process_http_request: wrote %d bytes data on socket successfully.\n",
                    (int) bytes_sent);
        }
        total_bytes_sent += (int) bytes_sent;
        printf("process_http_request: total bytes sent = %d\n",
                (int) total_bytes_sent);
        if (total_bytes_sent == strlen(http_request_buffer))
            break;
    }

    while (1) {
        printf("process_http_request: receiving bytes from server\n");
        memset(temp_buffer, 0, TEMP_BUFF_SIZE);

        bytes_received = recv(socketfd, temp_buffer, TEMP_BUFF_SIZE, 0);

        if (bytes_received == -1) {
            if (total_bytes_received == 0) {
                printf(
                        "process_http_request: Data could not be received from socket.\n");
                close(socketfd);
                return HTTP_ERROR_REC_FAILED;
            } else {
                printf(
                        "process_http_request: Timeout waiting for more data.\n");
                break;
            }
        } else if (bytes_received > 0) {
            sprintf(http_response_buffer, "%s%s", http_response_buffer,
                    temp_buffer);
            total_bytes_received += bytes_received;
            printf("process_http_request: total bytes received = %d\n",
                    (int) total_bytes_received);
        }
        if (bytes_received == 0) {
            printf("process_http_request: Data receiving finished.\n");
            close(socketfd);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("raw buffer=%s", http_response_buffer);
    response->raw_response = http_response_buffer;
    status = process_http_response(http_response_buffer, response);
    if (status == SUCCESS)
        printf("process_http_request: HTTP response parsed successfully.\n");
    else
        printf(
                "process_http_request: HTTP response parsing encountered problem. \n");
    return status;

}
```

The problem is that in almost all cases return me a page with 301 redirect and a link .For example for google's ip return me a redirect page to http://www.google.com/ , and I want the page itself and I don't know what to do.
Someone please help.Thank you!

Comment: A `301` redirect is a perfectly normal HTTP response. You are supposed to repeat the same HTTP request to the new URL provided in the response's `Location` header. For example, sending a request to `http://www.google.com` (note the missing trailing slash) might redirect you to `http://www.google.com/` (note the extra trailing slash). There is a difference between a blank path component and a `'/'` path component. You should normalize your input URLs before using them in HTTP requests. The path component in a normalized HTTP url always starts with a `/`, it is never blank.

Comment: Also, the `Host` request header should state the hostname from the URL, not the IP address you are actually connecting to. So, if you have a URL for `http://www.google.com` and you resolve `www.google.com` to `173.194.203.105`, the `Host` header should be `Host: www.google.com` and not `Host: 173.194.203.105`.

Comment: Please read the official HTTP 1.1 specification, [RFC 2616](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616) (and its successors RFCs 7230-7235).  HTTP is not a trivial protocol to implement from scratch.  You should do yourself a favor and use a pre-existing HTTP library, such as [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/).